# Data seeded in Laravel disappears and styling changes after running npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

Running npm run dev in my Laravel 10 + React + Inertia.js project, is causing Seeded data to vanish from the database, plus its causing unexpected styling changes in the app.

No migrations reset the database on npm run dev and .env DB configurations are standard. The issue occurs post data-seeding with php artisan db:seed and persists across server restarts.

Comment: Be sure to tag your question well so that it gets in front of the people best suited to help. This question is going to be specific to Laravel, and very very unlikely to be related to React, or general seeding.

Comment: npm run dev itself does not delete data in database. Maybe it is your code structure? Are you using docker and running `docker-compose down -v` when closing containers?